# file without extension: how to notice in bash script?

Tags: bash, makefile

I made a very simple script which tells me a file name and extension.
The script works as follows:

```
for file in * ; do 
    if [[ -f $file ]] ; then
        filename=${file##*/}
        basename=${filename%\.*}
        extension=${filename##*.}
        if [[ -n $extension ]] ; then
            echo "FILE: " $basename " ; ESTENSIONE " $extension
        fi
    fi  
done
```

The problem is that when I have a file without extension (e.g. Makefile) it says that the extension is the filename itself (e.g. extension= Makefile).
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you only want to process file names which contain a dot, change the first wildcard to `*.*`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the result you get is the expected one; I don't know if that means you're doing something wrong or not.

The way the pattern replacements work is that if the pattern doesn't match, nothing is replaced.  Here you have `${filename##*.}` which says remove all characters up to and including the final period.  But if there's no period in the name, then the pattern doesn't match and nothing is removed, so you simply get the same result as `${filename}`.

I should point out that the backslash in `${filename%\.*}` is useless: the pattern here is shell globbing not regular expressions, so you don't need to escape a period.  You can just write `${filename%.*}`.

*ETA:*

There's no way to do what you want in one step.  You have two choices; you can either test to see if the extension is the same as the filename and if so set it to empty:

```
extension=${filename##*.}
[ "$extension" = "$filename" ] && extension=
```

or you can strip off the basename, which you already computed, then get rid of any leading periods:

```
extension=${filename#$basename}
extension=${extension##*.}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! the problem is that I would like it to return an empty string if there's no extension. At this point I could check if extension and filename are the same, I guess

Comment: Well, that's not what you asked :-).

Answer (score 2):

Extensions don't have any privileged status in Unix file systems; they are just a part of the file name that people treat specially. You'll have to check if the file contains a `.` first.

```
    basename=${filename%\.*}
    if [[ $filename = *.* ]]; then
        extension=${filename##*.}
        echo "FILE: " $basename " ; ESTENSIONE " $extension
    else
        extension=""
    fi
```